# Can I define a fallback character in pdfLaTeX?

Tags: pdftex, unicode, input-encodings

I write most of my documents with XeLaTeX. Sometimes, however, i need to collaborate with someone who does not. In these cases, it is generally easy for me to add a pdfLaTeX-specific header:

```
\ifPDFTeX
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

The only issue is unicode characters:

> Unicode char ⟨charcode⟩ not set up for use with LaTeX

Can I tell inputenc to silently drop these characters, or replace them by a box, or some fallback character? For now the only solution I have is to define

```
\def\unic#1{\textvisiblespace}
```

and to wrap all unicode characters in this macro to hide them from pdfLaTeX, which is a pain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Macro `\UTFviii@defined` checks, whether the UTF-8 character is defined, it can be redefined. The following example replaces the undefined character by a box around its hexadecimal number (LaTeX/`utf8.def` should not be too old):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\UTFviii@defined}[1]{%
  \ifx #1\relax
    % \PackageError{inputenc}{%
    %   Unicode\space char\space
    %   \expandafter\UTFviii@splitcsname\string#1\relax\MessageBreak
    %   not\space set\space up\space for\space use\space
    %   with\space LaTeX%
    % }\@eha
    \noindent
    \begingroup
      \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{.2pt}%
      \tiny
      \fbox{%
        \expandafter\UTFviii@splithex\string#1\relax
      }%
    \endgroup
  \else
    \expandafter #1%
  \fi
}
\ifx\numexpr\@undefined
  \gdef\UTFviii@splithex#1:#2\relax{#2}}
\else
  \gdef\UTFviii@splithex#1:#2\relax{%
    \expandafter\UTFviii@hexnumber\expandafter{%
      \the\numexpr\decode@UTFviii#2\relax
    }%
  }
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Euro symbol: €
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks so much! Can you maybe explain how one finds about `\UTFviii@defined`?

Comment: @Clément It's a part of the internals of `inputenc`: you have to read the code to find it.

Comment: @Clément Another method for finding: `\tracingmacros=1\relax` before the undefined Unicode character, stopping the TeX job with `x` at the error message and analyzing the `.log` file backwards.