# Is there a way to determine if a character exists in a font in a macro?

Tags: fonts, macros

I'd like to make an `\interrobang` macro for my personal package of useful macros that prints the character `‽` (otherwise known as interrobang). However, some fonts don't have this character, and in that case I'd like to silently fall back to printing simply `!?`. Is there a way to do this?

What I get when I type the Unicode character in a macro and then use the macro in the document when the character is not available is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\u-default-8253 #1->\textinterrobang
```

Comment: Related: [Can I define a fallback character in pdfLaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/323570/2693)

Comment: The u-default-xxx naming that you are using  is non standard so you are presumably using some contributed package to set up characters. The answer will depend on that package mostly.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The only packages I'm using are: memoir (documentclass), [utf8x]{inputenc}, [T1]{fontenc}, mathpazo, berasans, microtype, tabularx, and my own package of macros (which does not itself load any packages). And I defined the interrobang macro as `\newcommand{\interrobang}{‽}. What in there might be causing the nonstandard notation?

Comment: yes it's utf8x (I'd use the standard utf8 unless there is something that really doesn't work in that case) (although `utf8x` is called as a package option to `inputenc` it is effectively a completely different package that redefines most of the original

Comment: It turned out that the OP’s problem was actually another one, but the sheer answer to the question as it is asked in the title is: exploit the `\iffontcher` conditional provide by e-TeX.

Comment: Interesting, never knew that -- I've just been copying this line from document to document for years, so I don't know why I used it initially. I'll see if it works the same without.

Comment: Of course, the name of the conditional that e-TeX provides is `\iffontchar`, *not* `\iffontcher`…

Answer (score 1):

The particular error that you show is unrelated to the font (tex never got that far) simply that the command is undefined, you can define

```
\providecommand\textinterrobang{!?}
```

then the error will go, and if any other font package defines this command to access a character in a font then `\providecommand` will do nothing.